# VariableSizedWrapGrid width mechanism

Tags: xaml, windows-8

I have a VariableSizedWrapGrid as my GridView ItemsPanel. The column the GridView lies within is set to Width Auto. I would expect the VariableSizedWrapGrid to use as much Space as it needs, but no, it only shows one item in the GridView, as opposed to a StackPanel. The stackpanel takes as much Space as it needs to show the items.

Is it a bug maybe ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to set width="*" this will fill up the space that is left within your stackpanel.

When set to Auto it will only take the space it needs based on the content within the grid.

A little while ago I wrote a blogpost about dynamic layouts with XAML, hope this will help you further in creating your layout:
http://www.playingwith.net/2012/01/creating-a-dynamic-layout-with-xaml-in-windows-8-metro-style-apps/